# What is the difference between these two variants of the word?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for a Latin translation of the word **arsonist**. Having made translations in various machine translation software it all narrows to two choices. One is **incendiarius** and the other is **incendarius**. I know nothing about Latin, sorry. I am willing to use the word alone without any context, hopefully meaning the same as **arsonist** in English. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll probably want to go with the former, **incendiarius**, as that is the [Classically-attested word](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DI%3Aentry+group%3D21%3Aentry%3Dincendiarius). It's actually an adjective, but it's used as a noun (meaning "arsonist") in Tacitus and Suetonius.

On the other hand, **incendarius** is a [Medieval variant](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DI%3Aentry+group%3D21%3Aentry%3Dincendiarius).

It might also be of interest for you that arsonist is a relatively recent coinage; the older word is [incendiary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=incendiary).